# My keyboard watcher stops working - apparently after focusing an 'input'?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have an Android WebView app I'm creating.

In the javascript, I start watching the 'body' for keypresses, while avoiding keypresses from 'inputs' and 'textareas', with the following code:

```
body.on('keyup', function (e) {
    let tag = e.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
    if (tag !== 'input' && tag !== 'textarea') {
        let kCd = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (kCd === 229) {
            return;
        } else if (kCd === 0) {
            kCd = 13; // enter key
        }
        window.keypresser.watch(kCd);
    }
});
```

I'm watching the body for keypresses because my device is one of these, connected to a barcode scanner:

[image]

My 'keypresser.watch' function accepts the keycode argument and either (a) appends to the scanned string, or (b) if enter is pressed, keycode 13, does a command within the app.

This works fine in the app when I'm debugging it in an Emulator, but when I have it on my physical device, it seems to stop working as soon as I focus on an `<input>` element. The 'enter' event still goes through - keycode 13 - but otherwise it seems to send through a blank string.

I've tried refocusing on 'body' but that doesn't fix it. I don't understand what's going wrong here.

If you want to test this, here's my window.keypresser object:

```
window.keypresser = {
    value: "",
    /** @param {Number} keycode */
    watch: function (keycode) {
        if (keycode === 13) {
            window.keypresser.enter(window.keypresser.value);
            window.keypresser.value = "";
        } else {
            window.keypresser.value += String.fromCharCode(keycode);
        }
    },
    enter: function (value) {
        // change this function to do things with the 'value'
    }
};
```

---

[edit]

What's weird is that in my Java code, I have my 'back' button set to

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

And so when I go back, move my task to back, and try the barcode scanner *again*, it works. Or also when I press the android 'overview' button twice, to defocus and then refocus the app - the keyboard starts working again. Maybe I can use this fact somehow to get my keyboard working again?

Comment: I'm not necessarily *just* looking for a direct answer to my question - you might tell me I'm interacting with this Barcode Scanner in the incorrect way, and there's a better way to watch for keyboard events from it. Please let me know if you have ideas in that direction as well.

Comment: Are you trying to capture `keyup` events on the `body` element even when you are focused inside an input field or is the requirement for all `keyup` events to be ignored in the context of `keypresser` while focused inside an input or textarea element?

Comment: **Furthermore**: Can you attach the `keyup` event to `window` instead? Alternatively I would suggest adding a callback for `blur` and `focus` events on `body` to test whether `body` is not losing focus in a predictable manner (i.e. the height/width is not set to 100% and when bluring out of input the actual focus on body is not reestablished, etc.)

Comment: @MattNewelski I am trying to avoid capturing events when I am focused inside an input. I realize now there is some ambiguous wording - it works initially, and then when I focus on an 'input' *and then try to focus somewhere else*, it stops working entirely (except apparently for keycode 13, enter).

Comment: @MattNewelski i tried $(document).on('keyup') but that's facing the same problem - it works, until i focus an input, then focus something else - then it ceases to work, until i double-press the Overview button

Comment: @MattNewelski also $(window).on('keyup'), again same issue.

Comment: @MattNewelski I add $('body').on('focus') and 'blur' watchers but they don't fire at all - the body itself doesn't really ever get focused or blurred apparently

Comment: Hey @TKoL since it seems you are comfortable with clicking on something to "restore" the key capture, have you considered using a button to toggle between "modes"? I apologize for "poking in the dark" but I am evaluating it from a web browser on Android perspective as I have no emulator handy.

Comment: @MattNewelski I spent all of friday trying to resolve this issue. I came up with a resolution - basically I watch for all 'blurs' on input and textarea elements, and when they blur, I trigger, in the Java, `myWebView.clearFocus()` -- I decided to try this because I noticed that my key watchers would start working again if I minimized and then brought up the app again. It's not ideal, it's kinda hacky, but it works.

Comment: Glad you found a workaround! Sometimes done is better than perfect :-)

Comment: @MattNewelski I'm also considering switching my global key watcher to be done on the Android side of things rather than in the javascript, because I think they characters are sometimes being scrambled in javascript. I can pass the events into the javascript through the javascriptinterface